# Type error: expected parameter accessToken in react Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, axios

Error screenshot:

[image]

While running react project by `npm start`, it shows error related to `contentful.js`. why does the package shows these types of error? I attached the screenshot with this post. How to solve this issue?

.env file

```
CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN: process.env.REACT_APP_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
```

config file

```
import SETTINGS from "../env";
const contentfulClient = contentful.createClient({
  space: SETTINGS.CONTENTFUL_SPACE,
  accessToken: SETTINGS.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN
});
```

Do i need to enter api token anywhere?

.env

```
const SETTINGS = {
  LANDING_BLOG_POSTS: "",
  ICON_TYPE: "svg",
  CONTENTFUL_SPACE: process.env.REACT_APP_CONTENTFUL_SPACE,
  CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN: process.env.REACT_APP_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  CLOUDINARY_UNSIGNED_PRESET: process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_UNSIGNED_PRESET,
  CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME: process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
  SERVER_7CHIP: process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_7HIP || false,
    HARD_CODED_USERNAME: process.env.REACT_APP_TOKEN_USERNAME || "**********",
  HARD_CODED_PASSWORD: process.env.REACT_APP_TOKEN_PASSWORD || "************",
  FACEBOOK_API_ID: process.env.REACT_APP_FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  FACEBOOK_PAGE_TOKEN: process.env.REACT_APP_FACEBOOK_PAGE_TOKEN,
  FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID: process.env.REACT_APP_FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID || "**************",
  FACEBOOK_SERVER_CALL: true
};
export default  SETTINGS;
```

Comment: can you console.log SETTINGS

Comment: I'm new to react Js. Where I console log? The error comes in all routes

Comment: inside your config.js after importing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your code got as far as getting into the `createClient` function, that tells me your SETTINGS object is loading (otherwise you'd get a TypeError from `accessToken: SETTINGS.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN`). However the error message says that no `accessToken` was provided.

Therefore `SETTINGS.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN` is `undefined`, `null` or an empty string. Since that value is set to `process.env.REACT_APP_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN` this probably means that you have not set your `REACT_APP_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN` environment variable before running the program.

Try setting that environment variable to your access token value, then running the program.

If that works, you might want to reconsider the approach. You have an "env" file but is getting values from system environment variables. Usually you have an "env" file so that you can hardcode values into it, not rely on them being set externally. If they have to be set externally you might as well not use an "env" file and just use `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME` directly in your code.

Note that if you hardcode access tokens or other private information in an "env" file, you should add that file to `.gitignore` so that passwords/keys are not stored in `git`.

Comment: Actualy i didnt get you. i m new in reaact and contentful. I was trying to run an old project,I think the accessToken value is null as you said. Where should i set REACT_APP_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN?..Where can i find it?

Comment: I coulnt find where REACT_APP_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN is been set in this project

Comment: may be you were right.. the environment file might be missing from my project. so it gets null value

Comment: The way you're set up, it expects an environment variable to be set outside of your program. Depending on the operating system it could be set with `export REACT_APP_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN=secret_value` (Linux/Mac) or `set REACT_APP_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN=secret_value` (Windows)

Comment: if you don't know the access token, then you need to get that from someone who can grant you access

Answer (score 1):

You created .env.development file same location as package.json file.

hope, this will help you.

Comment: Yes. The trick is to have the .env  in the same folder as the package.json file

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had the variables in the `.env` file in the source directory and just had to source it. I ran `. ./.env` and that sorted out the error in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case environment variables weren't accessible, because I created the .env file when my server was already running. I had to restart the server and everything worked like a charm.